# how to expand a category list imported from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, xampp

I have imported a set of different values from two different tables in phpMyAdmin, one from Category table (where cat_id is a PK) and another from Item table; where (cat_id is a FK).

```
<?php
require ('config.php');

$que = "SELECT * FROM category";
$run = mysql_query($que);
$j = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{
    $cat_idd[$j] = $row['cat_id'];
    $cat_namee[$j] = $row['cat_name'];
    $j++;
}
for($i = 0;  $i < count($cat_idd);  $i++)
{
    $que2 = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE cat_id = '$cat_idd[$i]' ";
    $result = mysql_query($que2);
    $run = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "<a href=''>".$cat_namee[$i]."(".$run.")</a><br>";
}
?>
```

Here is what I have so far:

[image: Screenshot]

Now how do I expand it? or for example, how do I show the two items that are stored in the category named Clothing on the same page or next? Since this code only helps me to view the number of items stored inside the database,

Here is my form:

```
    <form name = "view" method = "POST" action ="cart.php">
      <table align = 'center' width = '100%' border = '4'>
      <tr bgcolor = 'yellow'>
      <td colspan = '20' align = 'center'><h2> Viewing all the Products </td>
</tr>
      <tr align = 'center'>
      <th>Item ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Select</th>
      </tr>

      <tr  class = "odd">


      <?php
        require ('config.php');

        $que = "SELECT * FROM category";
        $run = mysql_query($que);
        $j = 0;
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
       {
         $cat_idd[$j] = $row['cat_id'];
         $cat_namee[$j] = $row['cat_name'];
         $j++;
       }
```

I thought of using an array function to store the value inside a category i.e `Clothing(2) => 2`.

```
       function array_insert(&$array, $position, $insert)
       {
         if (is_int($position)) {
          array_splice($array, $position, 0, $insert);
       } else {
          $pos   = array_search($position, array_keys($array));
          $array = array_merge(
             array_slice($array, 0, $pos),
             $insert,
            array_slice($array, $pos)
        );
       }
       }

      $arr = array();
      $arr[] = 2;


      for($i = 0;  $i < count($cat_idd);  $i++)
      {
       $que2 =  "SELECT * FROM item WHERE cat_id = '$cat_idd[$i]'";
       $result = mysql_query($que2);
       $run = mysql_num_rows($result);
       echo "<a href=''>".$cat_namee[$i]."(".$run.")</a><br>";
     array_insert($arr, 0, "$run");
     // echo $arr[0];
      }
        $que2 = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE cat_id = '1'";      //instead of using '1' i wish to use the one user clicks on!
        $res2 = mysql_query($que2);
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res2))
        {
          $i_id = $row['item_id'];
          $i_namee = $row['item_name'];
          $i_price = $row['item_price'];


       ?>
       <td><?php echo $i_id; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $i_namee; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $i_price; ?></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="addcart" value="<?php echo $item; ?>" onClick="return KeepCount()" />Tick</td>
</tr>
       <?php }  ?>    
       <br><br>
       </table>
       <input type = "hidden" name = "check">
       <button type=  "submit" onclick = "location.href = 'cart.php';" id = "cart" style="float:right; margin-top: 30px; margin-right: 10px;">Add to Cart</button>
```

The above image is the result what I want, this one is specific for Clothing(2) only. I want it to change as the user clicks on something else for example, Shoes(1).

Comment: Is `category` a physical table containing the data you provided? or is it a view? Can you provide more info on the way your items are stored?

Comment: @HPierce Yes, category is a physical table with data stored inside. the items are stored on the basis of category id (from category table) to  the item table. Like I said, I have two physical tables present in MySQL

Comment: I have edited the post with further information now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending almost a day or two I have finally got a way out of this and I'm posting the answer here so if anyone else comes here looking for it.

```
<?php
 require ('config.php');

 $que = "SELECT * FROM category";
 $run = mysql_query($que);
 $j = 0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
 {
    $cat_idd[$j] = $row['cat_id'];
    $cat_namee[$j] = $row['cat_name'];
  $j++;
 }
for($i = 0;  $i < count($cat_idd);  $i++)
    {
        $que2 = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE cat_id = '$cat_idd[$i]' ";
        $result = mysql_query($que2);
        $run = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo "<a href='c.php?id=$cat_idd[$i]'>".$cat_namee[$i]."(".$run.")</a><br><br>";
    }

?>


<?php
 require('config.php');
 if(isset($_GET['id']))
 { 
    $cat_id = $_GET['id'];
    $que = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE cat_id = '$cat_id'";
    $run = mysql_query($que);
?>
<br><br>
<form name = "view" method = "POST" action ="cart.php">
<table align = 'center' width = '100%' border = '4'>
<tr>
<td colspan = '20' align = 'center'><h2> Viewing all the Products </h2></td>
</tr>

<tr align = 'center'>
<th>Item ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Select</th>
</tr>

<tr align = 'center' class = "odd">
<?php

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
    {
        $i_id = $row['item_id'];
        $i_name = $row['item_name'];
        $i_price = $row['item_price'];
        ?>
<td><?php echo $i_id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $i_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $i_price; ?></td>
<?php

$item = $i_name ." ". $i_price;  

?>                                                      
<td><input type="checkbox" name="addcart[]" value="<?php echo $item; ?> />Tick</td> 
</tr>
<?php  }?><input type = "hidden" name = "check">
<button type=  "submit" onclick = "location.href = 'cart.php';" id = "cart">Add to Cart</button> <?php }  ?>  
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. You have SQL injection and possibly XSS issues here though, so don't go live yet. Search for "SQL injection" on this site to find resources on resolving this problem.

Comment: @halfer I am aware of SQL injection and this is just for the learning purpose, will work on that soon. Please elaborate XSS? :$

Comment: If you echo to the user anything that might have user input in it, they might have been able to put in `<>` HTML angle brackets. If so, they might have been able to add in script tags, in which case they might be able to run JavaScript inside your browser to do malicious things, like steal cookies. (Of course, there are also resources about that here, and on the web - it is worthy of research).

Answer (score 0):

You've issued the correct query to get all of the data information about an item. However, instead of getting the contents of each field, you've elected only to count the number of rows affected. By using `mysql_fetch_array()` you actually get the contents of each field and you can display the results.

Consider the following example based on your code:

```
for($i = 0;  $i < count($cat_idd);  $i++)
    {
        $que2 = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE cat_id = '$cat_idd[$i]' ";
        $result = mysql_query($que2);
        $run = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo "<a href=''>".$cat_namee[$i]."(".$run.")</a><br>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            //Change ['item_name'] and ['item_description'] to match your DB schema.
            echo "item name: $row['item_name']";
            echo "item description: $row['item_description']";
        }
    }
```

`$row` is an array (that is both associative and numerically indexed) containing all the data you are looking for. In my example, I assume the `items` table has a field named `item_name` and `item_description`. Your table *probably* has different columns names and you will need to change it to match your column names.

More info on `mysql_fetch_array()`:http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Finally, you should know that the `mysql` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5. You should strongly consider moving to either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

More info on `mysqli`: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

More info on `PDO`: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: i get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\inventory\c.php on line 57

Comment: Oops. I forgot a parenthesis on the line with the `while`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I fixed that before you mentioned :P but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: The issue was with this line echo "item name: $row['item_name']"; by changing it to echo  $row['item_name']; did the trick. However, this displays all the details even before the user has the chance to click on a category. How to fix that?

Comment: I thought that was what you intended. Sounds like you need a **second webpage** that generates all the item info. Just pass `cat_id` to a second script with `$_GET`.

Comment: No. What if I want to display the item_name and item_price (in my case) on the same page ONLY when the user clicks on the category (Clothing in current case) then? Should I pass the value accessed from database to a form or something?

Comment: That's much more of a Javascript question. You will need an AJAX call to your backend to fetch the results, and then display them on the page. I'm not confident enough in my JS skills to get this right on my first try, sorry.

Comment: Well. It's okay. I'll still keep looking for a way out. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @MuneerKhan: you don't need JavaScript here as far as I can see. When you generate those links, include a query string variable to include the PK of each row (e.g. `page.php?cat_id=4`). Clicking on one of those will go to self, with a query string var you can read and use to look up the products in that category.